# How to find the right additive polynomial in inverse affine transformation in AES

Tags: aes, rijndael

Addition polynomial affine transformation rijndael is (x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + x)

The affine transformation represented in A(x)

A(x) = (x^7 + x^6 + x^2 + x) + a(x)(x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + 1)mod x^8 + 1

Inverse of the multiplication can be found easily is (01001010) (x^6 + x^3 + x^1), so how to get the addition polynomial inverse affine transformation ?
it should be (01010000) (x^6 + x^4)

The inverse affine transformation represented in B(x)

B(x) = (x^6 + x^4) + a(x)(x^6 + x^3 + x^1)mod x^8 + 1

Comment: the additive polynomial is being xored, since xored operation is self inverse, u just need to xor the same additive polynomial in inverse operation.

Comment: What operations should be done to get the polynomial (x^6 + x^4) ? i don't understand xoring what with what ?

Comment: I am writing the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Affine Transformation for AES Sbox is given by

[image]

Let M b the 8x8 binary matrix and C be the affine additive constant then

B = M x A xor C --------------- (1)

The straight forward reverse to this transformation is

[image]

A = M<sup>-1</sup> * ( B xor C ) --------------- (2)

Where as the inverse of Affine Transformation is given as

[image]

Let D be the additive constant used in above inverse affine transformation then

A = ( M<sup>-1</sup> x B ) xor D --------------- (3)

Place value of B from (1) in (3)

A = ( ( M<sup>-1</sup> x (M x A xor C ) ) xor D

A = ( ( M<sup>-1</sup> x M x A) xor ( M<sup>-1</sup> x C ) ) xor D

Multiplying M with M<sup>-1</sup> will be Identity, thus

A = A xor (M<sup>-1</sup> x C) xor D

this implies

D = M<sup>-1</sup> x C

and thats how the additive constant in inverse affine transformation have been calculated.

in fact it is

[image]